# Jenkins Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin how to build only master and PR?

Tags: bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I'm using Jenkins 2 with the [Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Branch+Source+Plugin) which scans and builds all the branches and PRs.

My problem is that when I push code to a PR, the branch is built twice (one for the branch and one for the PR). I would like to build only master and PRs.

Do someone knows how to do that ? I can't find any documentation about this.

From the `Branch Indexing Log` (wihtout filter):

```
Checking branch branch-name from repo/project
Met criteria
Scheduled build for branch: branch-name
...
Checking PR from repo/project and branch branch-name
Met criteria
Scheduled build for branch: PR-123
```

Then when I try to filter on PR-* nothing is scanned. I just get:

```
Checking branch branch-name from repo/project
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are configuring your Bitbucket sources, you can use `Include branches` or `Exclude branches` (in `Advanced` params) to include/exclude some branches :

[image]

And based on [Bitbucket Branch source plugin source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-branch-source-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cloudbees/jenkins/plugins/bitbucket/BitbucketSCMSource.java), both fields takes an [Ant regex](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/regexp.html).

So assuming all your PR branches start with "**pr-**" you could use a regex in `include branches`, e.g. :

```
(?:master|pr-).*
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately if I filter `PR-.*` nothing is scanned

Answer (score 9):

You can just separate your terms with a space. For your include try:

```
master PR-*
```

Comment: This somehow works, but also isn't the behavior I was looking for. Now the branches disappear completely. I was looking for a solution where the branches are still shown and manual branch triggering is possible, but Jenkins won't build the branches automatically by default. Any ideas how to achieve that?